# Trying to 7-Zip individual files via Batch File

Tags: batch-file, 7zip, zip

The following code runs without error, but doesn't actually zip the files. I can't figure out my bug in the code line that begins "%ZipProgram%".

```
@echo off

:: Get the current directory.
set CurrDir=%cd%

:: Find the 7-Zip program.
set ZipProgram="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
if not exist %ZipProgram% (
    set ZipProgram="C:\Program Files (86)\7-Zip\7z.exe"
)
if not exist %ZipProgram% (
    set ZipProgram="C:\Program Files\Easy 7-Zip\7z.exe"
)
if not exist %ZipProgram% (
    set ZipProgram="C:\Program Files (86)\Easy 7-Zip\7z.exe"
)

:: %%n is the variable n specified in a batch file. From a command line it would be %n.
:: /D specifies loop through Directory names only.
FOR /D %%n in ("%CurrDir%\*.*") DO (
    %ZipProgram% u -y -t7z "%%n.7z" "%%n" -r -x!*.tmp
)

pause
```

Comment: At first, remove the `@echo off` and review the echoes...

Comment: You're setting a variable inside of a set of parentheses, so I'm guessing you need to use delayed expansion. Also, `u` is for updating existing archives while `a` is for creating new ones.

Comment: @ aschipfl - Thanks, should have posted it that way. I already had done that, and learned nothing. Output of the crucial loop part (otherwise this post exceeds length limits): |

`FOR / %n in ("D:\LocalData\New Folder\*.*") DO ("C:\Program Files\Easy 7-Zip\7z.exe" u -y -t7z "%n.7z" "%n" -r -x!*.tmp )' | `pause' | `Press any key to continue . . .'

Comment: @SomethingDark: delayed expansion. Yep, forgot about that.
Thanks on the 'u' versus 'a' comment, too.

Comment: Turns out it was the /D switch, which specificies looking in Directories, that I didn't want.
Delayed expansion sounded good, but wasn't the culprit (for once). 
The 'u' versus 'a' comment isn't a big deal: both create a new zip file if one doesn't exist; they only differ in what to do if A is already in the zip file, and you attempt to add a new copy. My next post will show what the correct line of code looks like.

Comment: for %%f in (*.*) do %ZipProgram%  a -y -t7z "%%~f.7z" "%%f"